# Hello World In C# without semicolon

Tags: c#, console

Is it possible to write `Hello World` like in `C` without semicolon`;`?

In `C`:

```
  if(printf("Hello World!"))  //prints Hello World
  { 
  }
```

In `C#`:

```
//do stuff
```

Comment: No, and even if you could, who cares?

Comment: @stian.net: because I have been asked in my practical VIVA

Comment: I don't know what a "VIVA" is, but if anyone asked me to do this I think I'd walk out. Good luck with your job hunting though; it's tough out there.

Comment: The downvoting on this question seems a bit harsh.

Comment: @Noon Silk: VIVA is the questions asked by examiner.

Comment: no!! if exactly say its not possible. There is lots of difference between printf return and Console.Writeln() return value. You should justify your Viva teacher with such argues

Comment: C and C# have largely the same syntax model. So this becomes: is there an output function w/o a `void` return type. Still rather pointless.

Comment: The question has yielded some very interesting answers. Shame it got closed.

Comment: @Banang remember that this is a Q&A site that is here to **help** people.  Not every question needs to help the entire community.  Try to be a little less harsh.

Comment: It's just an interesting problem without a practical application. People write quines too. And they are equally useless(but a bit harder to write).

Comment: Not expected for this type of response . `-ve votes, closed` :(

Comment: Its an interesting challenge and no more pointless than the code golf threads which are so popular here.

Comment: fwiw: viva is a short form of 'viva voce', which is latin for "with living voice" - often refers to an oral examination, usually at the end of a course of study for a masters or doctorate. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Viva_voce

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The trick is somehow constructing an expression from something that returns void. And luckily BeginInvoke does just that. Now we need to prevent the program from terminating before BeginInvoke wrote the text. Originally I just used a loop for that, but as SLaks showed we can use `.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne()` instead because it returns a `bool`.

Put this into the `Main` function:

```
if(((System.Action<string>)System.Console.WriteLine).BeginInvoke("Hello world",null,null).AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne())
{
}
```

Comment: Replaced endless loop with AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne from SLaks' answer.

Comment: Tried that in a console application - it requires `using System;` in order to work (SLaks' answer does not). Nice answer though.

Comment: Ah didn't notice that because I tested in LinqPad where the `using System;` is implicit.

Answer (score 8):

```
if (MessageBox.Show("Hello World") == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Yes)
{

}
```

Comment: However, this doesn't write to console.

Comment: The subject is to write without semi colon

Answer (score 6):

Like this:

```
class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        if (System.Console.OpenStandardOutput()
            .BeginWrite(new byte[] { 072, 101, 108, 108, 111, 032, 087, 111, 114, 108, 100, 033 },
                        0, 12, null, null)
            .AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne()) { }
        if (System.Console.ReadKey().Modifiers == 0) { }
    }
}
```

Comment: Very very nice! ;-)  This is my favourite code snippet of the year so far!

Comment: +1 for the `.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne()`. But it doesn't work in LinqPad for me. It either terminates before writing or doesn't terminate at all.

Comment: @Daniel: This works; I tried it.  @Code: Try it in a Console project.

Comment: Yes it works *now*, with the `Console.ReadKey()` you just added, because that flushes the console. You could do it all in one statement by passing the flush call as the callback for the async operation: `... 0, 12, a => Console.ReadKey(), null)`

Comment: I find it doesn't work with your byte array either, which is weird. I have to put Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("Hello World!")

Answer (score 5):

```
public static void Main()
{
    if (System.Console.WriteLine("Hello, World!") is object)
    {

    }
}
```

Existing answers either use a different output method than `Console.WriteLine` that doesn't return `void`, or use `Begin*` trickery to get a non-`void` expression out of a `void` method.  The trick here is that the left hand argument to `is` is permitted to be a `void` expression.  The compiler may warn that "expression is never of the given type", but the code is legal.

Answer (score 1):

Extending SwDevMan81's answer:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        if (MessageBox.Show("Hello World!") is System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult)
        {
        }
    }
```